# PyQt5 - setting the appearance of disabled QLabel pixmaps

Tags: pyqt5, qlabel

I have a GUI with some QLabels which have a PNG image / pixmap each. When I set a process to perform I also added *self.parent.setEnabled(False)* and *self.setEnabled(False)* so that the user cannot interupt the process. However, the pixmap images turn grey and I would like to set them so that they stay as they are without a grey cast on them. How is this possible? Would a stylesheet be the solution?

My code to disable user interaction during the process is:

```
def playVideo(self):
    global app
    app.setOverrideCursor(QCursor(QPixmap("./imgs/cursor.png")))
    self.parent.setEnabled(False)
    self.setEnabled(False)
```

Many thanks for any help in this.

Comment: You must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Updated now @eyllanesc

Comment: A mvce code besides being minimal and must be reproducible, you think your code is reproducible?

Comment: I have found the solution although I have yet to test it properly. Ironically it is from the QT Bug Tracker site (2011 Bug) but it does point towards a possible solution and details the issue better than I was able to. The way to solve the issue is here [link] (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-19008)

Comment: Apologies for my bad approach @eyllanesc

Comment: Ok, well that doesn't seem to work at all - I shall post a new question using the link mentioned a couple of comments ago